# Storyboard Sizes for iOS 11?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I currently use `Storyboard` for Screensizes.
The following storyboards I use are:

- iPhone55.storyboard
- iPhone47.storyboard
- iPhone4.storyboard
- iPhone35.storyboard

Each Storyboard corresponds to the screen size in the name.

Now with the iPhone X out, I need to create a new storyboard for this screen size.

However, my question is, what screensizes must I account for, with `iOS 11`?
And just out of curiosity, what screensizes must I account for, with `iOS 10`?

I'm finding conflicting information, so I thought I'd reach out here for clarification.
I'm thinking of making this update for iOS 11 users only, meaning I may be able to drop some older storyboards.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a horrible idea to me...you'll regret it at some point, trust me. Just image changing the size of a button, you'll have to do that 5 times. Oh boy.

Answer (score 1):

Separate storyboards for different screen sizes is a quick route to maintenance nightmares compared to Auto Layout, but whatever floats your boat...

That said, your set of supported screen sizes is correct for iOS **9** (which supports devices as far back as iPhone 4s, a 3.5" screen). iOS 10 drops support for 3.5" devices, but still supports 4" devices (iPhone 5s and iPhone SE, the latter of which remains for sale and will thus likely be supported for years to come). iOS 11 drops no further screen sizes (but does drop some... uh, bit sizes?), and of course, adds iPhone X.

Comment: I believe it was actually iOS 10 which dropped support for the 4s.

Comment: Indeed, you're correct: [wikipedia shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_10) iPhone 5/5C as the min spec for iOS 10. I thought to double-check with a different resource from a random web search, which was incorrect.

Comment: But iPhone-only apps run on an iPad require a 3.5" screen due to the iPhone emulation on the iPad.

Comment: I also use storyboards for iPad screensizes, so am I right in saying it wouldn’t emulate the iPhone 3.5?

Comment: @Reanimation If you have a universal app then you are correct. The app on the iPad will be a proper iPad app and not an emulated iPhone 3.5" app. If you have really have a storyboard for every possible screen size then you are really doing it wrong and you are making your life much harder than it should be. And you are also preventing yourself from supporting multitasking on an iPad. You should one storyboard total that works on all possible screen sizes.